# Swift Update Variables

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to swift and programming.
I want to do a simple app that can count things. You have one button to add +1 to a variable and one to subtract -1 from the variable. The variable should be shown as a text on the screen.

When I press a button the variable updates but the text not. Can somebody help me?

Thank you
`

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

var dats:Int = 2





struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("+") {
                dats += 1
            }
            Button("-") {
                dats -= 1
            }
            Text(amount)
        }
    }
}

var amount = String(dats)

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Check out some SwiftUI tutorials (Hacking with Swift, Apple, etc). You'll want to learn about `@State`, which is one of the fundamental concepts of the framework.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) it will be an uphill battle if you don't. SwiftUI won't know when to update Views when changes occur in global variables.

Answer (score 0):

- try hackingwithswift.com site and 100 days tutorials for swift, uikit, and swiftui

for your problem, attempt this, and try to find what the new term means

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var dats:Int = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("+") {
                dats += 1
            }
            Button("-") {
                dats -= 1
            }
            Text(String(dats))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```